# How to set a Spring profile to a package?

Tags: java, spring, spring-profiles

I want to set a profile name to a whole package and I don't know how. If where is no easy way then I have to mark every class in the package and sub packages with `@Profile` annotation.

`<context:component-scan/>` tag does not support attribute like `profile` so I have no idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't mix XML and Java config you could use `@Profile` on a bean which has `@ComponentScan` annotation with your target package maybe?

Similarly with XML: you can have two different `<beans ...>` sections, each with different profile and in each of the section you define your own `<context:component-scan basePackage="..." />`

```
@Configuration
@Profile("profile1")
@ComponentScan(basePackage="package1")
class Config1 {
}

@Configuration
@Profile("profile2")
@ComponentScan(basePackage="package2")
class Config2 {
}
```

Comment: And, we can specify active profile in the application.properties:

spring.profiles.active=profile1

Comment: it does not work with spring boot and with a NOT profile, i.e. @Profile("!dev")