# How to load property file based on spring profiles

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

How to create project architecture to support multiple envionment. Each environment will have different datasource from different property file like(dev-propertfile,test-propertyFil,Production-propertyfile) with help of spring's

```
org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
```

Comment: just use @Profie("profileName") - look at javadocs. http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'll give step by step procedure for Spring boot applications.

1. Inside **/src/main/resources/application.properties** mention **spring.profiles.active=dev** (or Prod)
2. Create **/src/main/resources/application-dev.properties** and give your custom dev configurations here.
3. Create **/src/main/resources/application-prod.properties** and give your custom prod configurations here.

Run.

Answer (score 12):

Put property file in same location as `application.property` and follow
the naming convention `application-{profile}.properties` like
`application-dev.properties`,`application-test.properties`,
`application-prod.properties`

And in `application.properties` set `spring.profiles.active=dev,test` etc

Comment: This will work only for Spring Boot, not for Spring MVC applications

Comment: This approach doesn't work if 2 or more profiles are set up simultaneouly

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70713277/7266331 <- wrote this answer for Spring MVC applications.

Answer (score 4):

For Spring Boot applications it will work easily even by using a YAML File

```
spring: 
  profiles: dev
  property: this is a dev env
---
spring: 
  profiles: prod
  property: this is a production env 
---
```

However, for a Spring MVC application, it needs more work. Have a look at [this link](http://littlebigextra.com/how-to-read-different-properties-file-based-on-spring-profile-in-a-spring-mvc-project/)

Basically, it involves 2 steps

1. Get the Spring Profile within servlet context

If you have set the profile on the server and want it to retrieve it within your application you can use System.getProperty or System.getenv methods.
Here is the code which fetches the profile and defaults it to a local profile, if no profile has been found.

```
private static final String SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE = "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE";
String profile;

/**
 * In local system getProperty() returns the profile correctly, however in docker getenv() return profile correctly
 * */
protected void setSpringProfile(ServletContext servletContext) {
if(null!= System.getenv(SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE)){
    profile=System.getenv(SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE);
}else if(null!= System.getProperty(SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE)){
    profile=System.getProperty(SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE);
}else{
    profile="local";
}
log.info("***** Profile configured  is  ****** "+ profile);

servletContext.setInitParameter("spring.profiles.active", profile);
}
```

2. To access the application-dev.properties, say now you will need to use
   @Profile("dev") at the class level

The following code will fetch the application-dev.properties and common.properties

```
@Configuration
@Profile("dev")
public class DevPropertyReader {


    @Bean
    public static PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer properties() {
    PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer ppc = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
    Resource[] resources = new ClassPathResource[] { new ClassPathResource("properties/common.properties"), new ClassPathResource("properties/application-dev.properties") };
    ppc.setLocations(resources);
    ppc.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
    return ppc;
    }
}
```

For accessing say application-prod.properties you have to use `@Profile("prod")` at the class level. More details can be  [found here](http://littlebigextra.com/how-to-read-different-properties-file-based-on-spring-profile-in-a-spring-mvc-project/)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Spring Profile](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html). You will define a set of profiles configurations, like Test, Dev, Production. And then, when you launch the application, you can define wich profile it should use.

Here are some [tutorials](https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-profiles-example/) of how to use.

And this guys had the same problem as yours: [How to config @ComponentScan dynamic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40359838/how-to-config-componentscan-dynamic/40359948#40359948)

Answer (score 2):

We wanted a way to load different properties from `application-<your_env>.properties` file depending on the environment (spring profile) in a Spring MVC project, so we implemented a configuration class something like this.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource({ "classpath:application-${envTarget:dev}.properties" })
@Data
public class EnvironmentConfig {

    @Value("${files.s3.accessId:}")
    String s3AccessId;

    @Value("${files.s3.accessToken:}")
    String s3AccessToken;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Then we loaded the `EnvironmentConfig` in the class where we needed to use it.

While running the application, you just need to pass the `-DenvTarget=<your_env>`, and it will pick up the `application-<your_env>.properties` file from `src/resources` folder of the project.

In the above code, it will load values from `application-dev.properties` files when no `envTarget` is specified.

Thanks to Karthikeyan Muthurangam for suggesting this clever solution.