# i cant access data from my properties in java spring boot

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, selenium, cucumber

i have properties named application-QA1.properties

```
#Endpoint
web.loginPage=https://www.phptravels.net/

#login data
common.data.username=tes
common.data.password=tes

#Default Param
param.storeId=10001
param.channelId=tes-web
param.clientId=10001
param.requestId=RANDOM
param.businessChannel=web
param.requestParams={}
param.test=true
```

and i put it in:

```
src/test/resources
```

and i create class as instance for that properties named WebProperties.java

```
package com.project.automation.ui.properties;

import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Data
@Component("com.project.automation.ui.properties.WebProperties")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "web")
public class WebProperties {
    private String loginPage;
}
```

and i put it in:

```
src/main/java/mypackage/properties
```

and i want to access that class variable on LoginPage.java

```
package com.project.automation.ui.pages;

import com.project.automation.ui.models.xpath.CommonXpathModel;
import com.project.automation.ui.properties.CommonProperties;
import com.project.automation.ui.properties.WebProperties;
import lombok.Data;
import net.serenitybdd.core.pages.PageObject;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Data
@Component("com.project.automation.ui.pages.LoginPage")
public class LoginPage extends PageObject {

  @Autowired
  CommonPage commonPage;

  @Autowired
  CommonXpathModel commonXpathModel;

  @Autowired
  WebProperties webProperties;

  @Autowired
  CommonProperties commonProperties;

  public void openPage(){
    //on this code i want to get that properties value through its class instance
    getDriver().get(webProperties.getLoginPage());
  }
}
```

the page i put it in:

```
src/main/java/mypackage/pages
```

and this is my pom.xml located in root of my project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.project.automation.ui</groupId>
    <artifactId>wina</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <serenity.version>1.9.45</serenity.version>
        <maven.failsafe.plugin>2.22.0</maven.failsafe.plugin>
        <selenium.version>3.14.0</selenium.version>
        <buildDirectory>${project.basedir}/target</buildDirectory>
        <serenity.testlink.integration.version>3.4.5</serenity.testlink.integration.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mustache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.lambdaj</groupId>
            <artifactId>lambdaj</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.8</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-core</artifactId>
            <version>${serenity.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-cucumber</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.45</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${serenity.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>${serenity.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <directory>${buildDirectory}</directory>
        <testOutputDirectory>${buildDirectory}/test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
        <outputDirectory>${buildDirectory}/classes</outputDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.properties</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.failsafe.plugin}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>integration-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/CucumberRunner.java</include>
                    </includes>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <cucumber.options>--junit,--step-notifications</cucumber.options>
                        <spring.config.location>classpath:/application-QA1.properties</spring.config.location>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.serenity-bdd.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>serenity-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${serenity.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>serenity-reports</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>aggregate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

but it keeps return *null*.

please help me, i already read many tutorial but still no luck, beside i am beginner at spring boot. thank you

Answer (score 1):

The problem is naming convention of properties file, Since you named it as `application-QA1.properties` it becomes profiles specific properties file [Profile-specific properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.5.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties) and you can load those properties by making profile active in `application.properties` like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41263105/how-to-load-property-file-based-on-spring-profiles)

```
spring.profiles.active=QA1
```

Or through command line

```
java -jar myproject.jar --spring.profiles.active=QA1
```

And another information, value in `@Component` annotation indicates the bean name

> he value may indicate a suggestion for a logical component name, to be turned into a Spring bean in case of an autodetected component.

Comment: thank you for the reply, but the things is my project also cant read application.properties value. so the main problem was cannot read properties value, maybe i put the file wrong. i put all properties file in src/test/resources. maybe i should put that file inside src/main/resources ?

Comment: Yes that's correct you have to move them to 'src/main/resources' @AhmadLeoYudanto

Comment: yes, i already moved that while ago. but still no luck, maybe i need to mvn clean or something? the properties now moved to target/classes after i run the project via cucumberRunner.java (before the properties belongs in target/test-classes )

Comment: sorry i think i'm confused, is this for test cases ? or for main application @AhmadLeoYudanto ?

Comment: sorry to make you confused, i just want to read the properties values that it. but i found new problem, even when i set the value of loginPage variable not using application-QA1.properties values it still return null. so i think its not read properties value problem but autowired and component things. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You indicated that the location of your properties file is:

```
<spring.config.location>classpath:/application-QA1.properties</spring.config.location>
```

But you put the properties file inside a package directory...

```
src/main/java/mypackage/properties
```

So when you build the project, the properties file is not going to end up in the root of your classpath... It is going to end up in the same package directory of your classpath. See for yourself.

Comment: thank you for the reply, but i put my properties file inside src/test/resources. and properties class inside src/main/java/mypackage/properties.